# How can I make my bluge index merge more often to make it smaller?

Tags: go

I Store some text Files in bluge. They do change frequently and are not very large individually. For Files that are about 10MB in size the index however is about 1,2 GB.

I have very frequent changes to the index and the index folder contains more that 1600 segment filese. I would have expected that they are merged automatically